# NAudio Volume Changing

Tags: c#, naudio

```
class Sound
{

    private NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream stream = null;
    private NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut output = null;
    private string fileName;

    public Sound(string fileName)
    {

        this.fileName = fileName;

    }
    public void PlaySound()
    {

        if(fileName.EndsWith(".mp3"))
        {
        NAudio.Wave.WaveStream pcm = NAudio.Wave.WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(fileName));
        stream = new NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream(pcm);

        }
        else if (fileName.EndsWith(".wav"))
        {
            NAudio.Wave.WaveStream pcm = new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(fileName));
            stream = new NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream(pcm);
        }
        else throw new InvalidOperationException("Not a correct audio file type.");

        output = new NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut();
        output.Init(stream);
        output.Play();
        output.Volume = 0.5f;
    }
    public void Volume(float vol)
    {

    }
    public void PausePlay()
    {
        if (output != null)
        {
            if (output.PlaybackState == NAudio.Wave.PlaybackState.Playing) output.Pause();
            else if (output.PlaybackState == NAudio.Wave.PlaybackState.Paused) output.Play();
        }
    }
    public void Pause()
    {
        if (output != null)
        {
            if (output.PlaybackState == NAudio.Wave.PlaybackState.Playing) output.Pause();
        }
    }
    public void Play()
    {
        if (output != null)
        {
            if (output.PlaybackState == NAudio.Wave.PlaybackState.Paused) output.Play();
        }
    }
    public void DisposeWave()
    {
        if (output != null)
        {
            if (output.PlaybackState == NAudio.Wave.PlaybackState.Playing) output.Stop();
            output.Dispose();
            output = null;
        }
        if (stream != null)
        {
            stream.Dispose();
            stream = null;
        }
    }
    public bool Over()
    {
        if (stream.Position == stream.Length)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public void Loop()
    {

        if (Over())
        {
            stream.Position = 0;
            output.Play();

        }

    }
```

I really don't know what's the problem here, I'd be glad for a help, I'm trying to change the volume of the output audio.
When I compile this code I'm getting an error in the `output.volume = 0.5`. The error is:

> Setting volume not supported on DirectSoundOut, adjust the volume on your WaveProvider instead.

Comment: +1 for `new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(fileName))` trick, it helped me to access `Volume` property when using Mp3FileReader (which doesn't contains this property itself).

Answer (score 6):

It means, use the `Volume` property on `WaveChannel32` instead. Also, unless you are using an old version of NAudio, the `BlockAlignReductionStream` and the `WaveFormatConversion` stream are unneccessary, since `MP3FileReader` emits PCM.